# Carry over working multi-query MySQL to PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

The following works as intended in MySQL (phpMyAdmin):

```
SET @randomComposer=(SELECT composer FROM compositions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1);
SELECT * FROM compositions WHERE composer!='' AND composer=@randomComposer;
```

But I am unable to carry this over into PHP. Using query concatenation, syntax highlighting fails at the start of the SET… line and I get an error querying the database. How do I convince PHP to recognise the working MySQL?

(Research brought me to mysqli_multi_query, which I understand is the route I need to follow, but I first need to sort out PHP's aversion to SET.)

Comment: It looks like that first line should work as a subquery if you want to try doing it with just one statement.

Comment: I already tried the subquery approach, but without success. In that case I used the SELECT … ORDER BY RAND … portion of the first line, without setting the variable.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would try to do it with one statement.

```sql
SELECT compositions.* FROM compositions
INNER JOIN
(SELECT composer FROM compositions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) AS RandComposer
ON compositions.composer = RandComposer.composer
```

You may need to add the `WHERE composer!=''` to the subquery.

Comment: You're a star! I'd been going round and round in circles with variations on  what I thought was a subquery approach, all without success (syntax error after syntax error). Now I've tried out your code and it works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks again. I'd already spotted the WHERE composer!='' bit myself and have successfully added it. I'll sleep well tonight!